# Accessing private method in Java

Tags: java

In java, a private access modifier is highly restrictive which can be accessed only within the class in which they are defined.

Consider the example.

```
    package x;
    public class Boom {

    protected String name;

    public Boom() {

    }

    private void aConfidentialInfo(){
        System.out.println("Some confidential information...");
    }

    protected void display(){
        System.out.println("In display method..");
        aConfidentialInfo();
    }

}

package y;
import x.Boom;

public class Hack extends Boom{

    public Hack{
        display();
    }   

}
```

Here when I run class `Hack`, it calls display followed by `aConfidentialInfo` which is a private member of class `Boom`. How is class `Hack` able to access the private member of class `Boom`? Isn't it the infringement of private access modifier. How to understand and explain this with some decent reasoning?

Comment: It can't access aConfidentialInfo() directly.  It *CAN* access display().  If display() has functionality in one context (when it's invoked from the base class), why would you expect it to have any different functionality when it's invoked in a different context (from a derived class).  There is absolutely Nothing Wrong with This Picture :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it accesses a protected member of Boom-  display.  That's legal-  a subclass or anything in the package can access a protected member.  That protected function can access private members, because that protected function is part of the class Boom.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible due to the *magic* of polymorphism.

Hack **extends** Boom and thus has access to all public, package, and protected fields and methods. It thus can call the protected `display()` method. With the magic of polymorphism, calling display in Hack calls Boom's method which is able to call `aConfidentialINfo()`